# if i call reload function before ajax call then can ajax execute or not?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, api

if i call reload function before ajax call then can ajax execute or not?

```
function my_status_update(id,va){
      $(".close-menu").trigger("click");
      var status = va;
      var id = id;
     $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url : base_url+'home/update_status_job_naha?id='+id+'&&val='+status,
        data: {status:status,id:id},
        success: function(){
                 
               },
            });
                 location.reload();
        } 
    
 public function update_status_job_naha(){
        $status = $_REQUEST['val'];
        $id = $_REQUEST['id'];
                $data = array(
                 'shipping-status' => $status,
                 'shipping_status' => $status,
                 'status_change_dt' => date('d-m-Y  h:i:sa'),
                );
             $this->db->where('id', $id);
             $this->db->update('one_table', $data);
             $d_id=$this->session->userdata('user_id');
             $status = $_REQUEST['val'];
             $id = $_REQUEST['id'];
                $data = array(
                 'tracking_reference' => $id,
                 'shipping_status' => $status,
                 'updated_by' => $d_id
                );
              $this->db->insert('second_table',$data);
        if ($status=='Delivered' && isset($_REQUEST['amount'])) {
              $ins_am=0;
              $amount = $_REQUEST['amount'];
              $d_id=$this->session->userdata('user_id');
              $amount_d_b  = $this->Common_Model->get_wallet_amount_ofdriver($d_id);
              $ins_am =($amount_d_b[0]->delv_amount+$amount);
              $dataam = array('delv_amount' => $ins_am );
             $this->db->where('id', $d_id);
             $this->db->update('third_table', $dataam);
      }
    $url = 'https://this_is_a_api/notify-order-status/';
     $ch = curl_init($url);
     $payload = array(
       'tracking-reference'=>$id, 'shipping-status'=>$status
    );
    $data = json_encode($payload);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
                    'Content-Type:application/json',
                    'Media type:: application/json'
                ));
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
             return true;
    }
```

here  `$url = 'https://this_is_a_api/notify-order-status/';` this is very slow.

my issues are:

- i update status with ajax call
- in ajax call have a api link (that link was very slow.when i got the response i become a old man )

what i need:

- api response no matter about me that will update in background
- reload my page with new status

Comment: Is reloading the page after the `POST` request returned a reply an option for you?

Comment: that's not necessary.but may i need change the 'status' in my page <3

Comment: If you move the `reload` into the `success` method in your ajax request, you will reload the page after the POST request has been handled

Comment: bro my ajax url have api link.responding that link is too slow.so get ajax succes take too much time that is my issue

Comment: I'd say that, if you really want to `reload()`, you probably should do it in a `success` handler.  Otherwise – why did you make the AJAX call at all?

Comment: @mike robinson then how can i pass a value to api while changeing a status